# How can I achieve a similar result to naming each instance of a class after the values of different strings?

Tags: java, string, class, dictionary, hashmap

I am looking to achieve the same result as doing the following:

I have a class named `Territory`, of which each instance will be named a value of `String[] countryNames`. `Territory` has two internal variables, `player` and `numberOfArmies`.

To create each `Territory` instance (`public Territory(String player, int numberOfArmies)`), I would create a loop that iterates through each `countryNames`, creates a new `Territory` of this name, and assigns a `player` and `numberOfArmies` to this `Territory`. Something along the lines of:

```
countryNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length(); i++) {
    Territory countryNames[countryNumber] = new Territory(playerNames[j], 0);
    countryNumber++;
}
```

This is a simple example that assumes there are the same number of players and countries. This would not be the case in my program - players can be assigned to more than one territory.

I know that Java doesn't support taking the value of a String and assigning it to the name of a variable - so what other way can I create some sort of data structure where each element is given a name and two variables? I haven't really studied maps in Java, but I think that some sort of map would possibly be the solution.

Comment: If a Territory is supposed to have a name, why isn't there a name attribute inside the Territory class?

Comment: Because the only time the name would need to be used would be to access the class and get the `player` and `numberOfArmies`. By giving it an internal `name` variable, I would then have the name of the country inside the class, but still need to associate the actual name of this instance of the class with a country.

Comment: What's the difference between associating a player name to a territory and a country name to a territory? I see that as basically the same thing: a territory is for a given country, and for a given player. So, why is it OK to have a playerName attribute in the Territory, and not to have a countryName in it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it - its just that I still have to externally associate each `Territory` with each country. If I have 50 countries and want to find out which player occupies Australia, I would have to find the `Territory` associated with Australia. The best way I see of doing this would be by calling `Australia.getPlayer()`.

Comment: No. That's not possible. You can't dynamically create variables. But you can loop over all the territories (that would be stored in an array or in a list), find the one which has the country "Australia", and get the player name out of it. Of course, using a Map<String, Territory> is fine, too, but those are not contradictory technique. If a Territory is associated to a country, you might need to do someTerritory.getCountry() to know it, instead of having to go to a Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a HashMap:

```
HashMap<k,v> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Where k whould be the string name and v the element. To add and entry to the HashMap you have to use the **.put(k,v);** method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still need to store the `numberOfArmies` associated with each `Territory`. Is it possible to create a HashMap with a key and 2 variables?

Comment: numberOfArmies is a variable in Territory so just add the whole object tho the hashMap.  

    map.put(name, new Territory(player, numberOfArmies);

Comment: @CornOnTheKob a Map can contain any kind of object. You want a `Map<String, Territory>`. Why don't you read the collections tutorial and the javadoc? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: @Carles ok I understand. So if I have a `getPlayer()` method within the class and call `map.put("Australia", new Territory("John", 10))`, can I access this name by calling `map.get(Australia.getPlayer())`?

Comment: No, you access the name via `map.get("Australia").getPlayer()`. `map.get("Australia")` delivers the `Territory` object that belongs to Australia.

Comment: @CornOnTheKob A HashMap is kind of an ArrayList for example, but it has a key and a value. In the example you gave me Australia vould be the key as a String and Territory the value. To get the key you have to iterate through the whole map.
'
for (Map.Entry<String, Territory> t : map.entrySet())
{
if(t.getKey().equals("Australia"))
//Your code here
}
'
Also keep in mind that if you want to use the object Territory you have to use t.getValue() and then for example .getNumberOfArmies